# How do I get native GeoIP support in nginx under Alpine Linux

Tags: php, nginx, geoip, alpine-linux

Under OS X and Ubuntu I use GeoIP in PHP through nginx like this:

```
nginx.conf:
geoip_country /somepath/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;

php:
$country = $_SERVER["GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE"]
```

However under Alpine Linux, the package version of nginx (`apk add nginx`) doesn't seem to include GeoIP (confirmed by `nginx -V`).

I could compile nginx from source with `--with-http_geoip_module`, but then I'd have to update nginx manually, which is not desirable. My current workaround is the following:

```
ash:
sudo apk add geoid

php:
$country = exec("geoiplookup $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]");
```

How do I get native GeoIP support in nginx under Alpine Linux?

**Update: `geoip_country` is not recognised even though I installed from edge.**

```
$ apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.4.4-36-ge528256 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main]
v3.4.0-4239-gff0f660 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community]
v3.4.0-4267-ga3e3a29 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main]
OK: 12899 distinct packages available
$ apk add nginx@edge nginx-mod-http-geoip@edge
(1/5) Installing libressl2.4-libcrypto@edge (2.4.3-r1)
(2/5) Installing pcre (8.38-r1)
(3/5) Installing libressl2.4-libssl@edge (2.4.3-r1)
(4/5) Installing nginx@edge (1.10.1-r9)
Executing nginx-1.10.1-r9.pre-install
(5/5) Installing nginx-mod-http-geoip@edge (1.10.1-r9)
Executing busybox-1.24.2-r11.trigger
OK: 500 MiB in 92 packages
$ rc-service nginx restart
 * Caching service dependencies ...                                                                                             [ ok ]
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "geoip_country" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed                                                                     [ !! ]
 * ERROR: nginx failed to start
```

Answer (score 4):

I’ve updated the nginx package, i.a. added support for GeoIP as a dynamic module. It’s in package [nginx-mod-http-geoip](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/nginx-mod-http-geoip).

---

This package is not in any stable release yet (will be in v3.5), so you have to use edge. If you’re on stable v3.4, you can install just specific packages from edge using [repository pinning](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Repository_pinning):

```
echo "@edge http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories
apk update
apk add nginx@edge nginx-mod-http-geoip@edge
```

However, nginx in edge is built against newer versions of libraries than you have from the stable branch, so it *may* not work correctly (if there is some ABI incompatible change).

In this case you can build [nginx](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/tree/master/main/nginx) package [yourself](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Creating_an_Alpine_package#Setup_your_system_and_account) or just use backported package from [my repository](https://github.com/jirutka/aports):

```
echo "@geeknet https://alpine.geeknet.cz/packages/v3.4/backports" >> /etc/apk/repositories
wget -O /etc/apk/keys/jakub@jirutka.cz-56d0d9fd.rsa.pub https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jirutka/aports/v3.4/.keys/jakub@jirutka.cz-56d0d9fd.rsa.pub
apk update
apk add nginx@geeknet nginx-mod-http-geoip@geeknet
```

Comment: Thanks for quick handling! Please post a comment when it's available through the package system.

Comment: `geoip_country` is not recognised even though I installed from edge. How can I resolve this?

Comment: @forthrin Have you updated nginx.conf after update? Do you have `include /etc/nginx/modules/*.conf;` in it on top-level?